# How can I make this HTML / CSS file UltraHD / 4k friendly in a CHtmlView?

Tags: html, css, webbrowser-control

I have a simple HTML / CSS file.

```css
<style type="text/css">
table {
 font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
}
thead tr td {
 font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 12pt;
 background-color: gray;
}
td {
 font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
 border-bottom: 1px black solid;
 border-top: 1px black solid;
 border-left: 2px black solid;
 border-right: 2px black solid;
}
h1 {
 font-family: "Arial Unicode MS";
 text-align: center;
}
.columnStudyPoint {
}
.columnDate {
 text-align: center;
 /*width: 10%;*/
}
.textStudyPoint {
 font-weight:700;
}
.textStudyDescription {
 
}

@media print {
   thead {
       display: table-header-group;
   }

   table tbody tr td:before,
   table tbody tr td:after {
        content : "" ;
        height : 4px ;
        display : block ;
    }
}
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="CounselForm.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>Student Counsel Forms</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Counsel Form for Happy Face</h1>
<table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
 <colgroup>
  <col width="100%" /><col /><col />
 </colgroup>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td class="columnStudyPoint">Study Point</td>
   <td class="columnDate">Date Assigned</td>
   <td class="columnDate">Date Completed</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">1</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Accurate 
  Reading</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">2</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Words 
  Clearly Spoken</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">3</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Correct 
  Pronunciation</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">4</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Fluent 
  Delivery</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">5</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Appropriate 
  Pausing</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">6</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Proper 
  Sense Stress</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">7</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Principal 
  Ideas Emphasized</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">8</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Suitable 
  Volume</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">9</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Modulation</span>
  </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">10</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Enthusiasm</span>
  </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">11</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Warmth 
  And Feeling</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">12</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Gestures 
  and Facial Expressions</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">13</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Visual 
  Contact</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">14</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Naturalness</span>
  </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">15</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Good 
  Personal Appearance</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">16</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Poise</span>
  </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">17</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Use 
  of Microphone</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">18</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Use 
  of Bible in Replying</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">19</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Use 
  of Bible Encouraged</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">20</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Scriptures 
  Effectively Introduced</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">21</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Scriptures 
  Read With Proper Emphasis</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">22</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Scriptures 
  Correctly Applied</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">23</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Practical 
  Value Made Clear</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">24</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Choice 
  of Words</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">25</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Use 
  of an Outline</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">26</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Logical 
  Development of Material</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">27</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Extemporaneous 
  Delivery</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">28</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Conversational 
  Manner</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">29</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Voice 
  Quality</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">30</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Interest 
  Shown in the Other Person</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">31</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Respect 
  Shown to Others</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">32</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Expressed 
  With Conviction</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">33</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Tactful 
  Yet Firm</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">34</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Upbuilding 
  And Positive</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">35</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Repetition 
  for Emphasis</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">36</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Theme 
  Developed</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">37</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Main 
  Points Made to Stand Out</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">38</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Interest 
  - Arousing Introduction</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">39</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Effective 
  Conclusion</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">40</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Accuracy 
  of Statement</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">41</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Understandable 
  to Others</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">42</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Informative 
  to Your Audience</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">43</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Use 
  of Assigned Material</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">44</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Effective 
  Use of Questions</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">45</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Illustrations 
  / Examples That Teach</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">46</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Illustrations 
  From Familiar Situations</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">47</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Effective 
  Use of Visual Aids</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">48</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Reasoning 
  Manner</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">49</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Sound 
  Arguments Given</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">50</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Effort 
  To Reach the Heart</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="columnStudyPoint"><span class="textStudyPoint">51</span>&nbsp;<span class="textStudyDescription">Accurately 
  Timed, Properly Proportioned</span> </td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="columnDate">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

My CSS file sets **font sizes** and **line thicknesses**. These are what I am interested in.

The results look fine on my computer running a high resolution (but not UltraHD etc.). I don't have a UltraHD monitor in order to test this out to see if it will work correctly.

Ultimately this webpage will be shown in a `CHtmlView` browser control so it does not need to be compatible with all mobile devices.

Thank you.

## Update

Here you see it in context in my application:

[image: Counsel Form]

I note the comments state that I should not be specifying font heights myself. I saw this:

https://websemantics.uk/articles/font-size-conversion/

It refers to `1em` for `12pt`.

## Update

Someone has just tried my `CHtmlView` application on a Ultra HD computer. The preview is fine. But the printing to PDF or a Printer looks like this:

[image: Print]

It is cropped.

If I get them to open the same file directly in Internet Explorer and  print it it prints correctly to the printer and PDF.

So why is `CHtmlView` playing up?

Comment: One thing I would recommend is not using the unit `pt` for font-sizes. `pt` is more for print (print stylesheets) and not screens. I would recommend using a relative font size like `em` or `rem`. You can read about the differences [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/)

Comment: @zgood. OK. In my application I do have a Print Preview button. Utimately the user will want to print this to a printer or PDF on Letter or A4 paper.

Comment: Use `pt` in the `@media print` section.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan just read a bit on these `em` values. If I put the font size in the `@media print` section then what actual `em` value do I use for the screen? I assume a similar issue for the line thicknesses.

Comment: As @zgood mentioned, `em` is a *relative* size. In this case, it's relative to the size of the font as determined by the user in their browser settings. You should not specify a font size for screen, especially when dealing with many different screen sizes.

Comment: Ok, so use 1em then. What about the font weight and pixel thicknesses? Are there issues there?