# CHtmlView that is compatible with UltraHD

Tags: mfc, webbrowser-control

`CHtmlView` is not compatible with UltraHD resolutions. It is not simply down to using the correct HTML/CSS to be UltraHD aware. The print preview mechanism fails and crops the page. Many months ago Microsoft acknowledged this as an issue and has not addressed it.

My application heavily uses a `CHtmlView` element for displaying schedules and printing. Whilst my application is Windows based (Win32/x64) I am getting more and more users on Mac computers running Windows inside it and they all are always using UltraHD by default. As a result my application fails to function properly and the user has to reduce the resolution and adjust text scaling back to 100%.

Has anyone else encountered this issue with using UltraHD with `CHtmlView` print preview and got it working?

The related question is here:

[How can I make this HTML / CSS file UltraHD / 4k friendly in a CHtmlView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284018/how-can-i-make-this-html-css-file-ultrahd-4k-friendly-in-a-chtmlview)

But I asked that ages ago and got nowhere so I am trying again.

Thank you.

## Update

I provided this XSL script to the user to try with Ultra HD resolution in my program:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; border: thick solid #00FF00;">This is a test
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So it uses the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` code and it has made no difference. When he does a print preview:

[image: Preview]

So the problem still remains. It seems to be something to do with the **Print Preview** mechanism of the `CHtmlView` control.

## Update

This is Microsoft link to this issue:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/215368/chtmlview-and-printing-on-ultrahd-computers.html

Still not resolved.

Comment: Do you use the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Registry Key or the Compatibility Meta Tag to [target a newer version of the browser control](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/)? By default, the browser control is in compatibility mode, which means it emulates a very old version (like IE 7!)

Comment: [FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/ee330730%28v%3dvs.85%29#browser-emulation).

Comment: @zett42 I have not ever used or known about this meta tag. My documents are XSL / XML transformations so I should be able to add this meta tag. So, are you suggesting that IE7 in itself will not cope with Ultra HD? I will have to get this tested by a user.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me. IE7 is almost 12 years old now.

Comment: @zett42 Ok I will get it tested.

Comment: @zett42 I have added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` to my XSL file in the `<head>` section. Is there a specific test I can do I my end for something that will only work with latest IE so I can verify it? Then I can send it to the user for the UltraHD test.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11) lists some new features of IE11 like WebGL which you could try to use.  [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) lists CSS3 support for different browser versions. Interesting read: [High DPI support in IE11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/dn265030(v=vs.85))

Comment: @zett42 I have just done a test with `align-items` and confirm it renders correctly inside my `CHtmlView` browser. So now I need to get the user to try.

Comment: @zett42 Updated question with results.